# a20 gate is enabled, after disabling attempts

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader

I've encountered a problem with disabling (for learning purpose) a20 gate.

Here is my bootloader code:

```
onboot:
    xorw %ax, %ax
    movw %ax, %ds
    movw %ax, %es
    movw %ax, %ss   
    movw $0x7c00, %ax
    movw %ax, %bp
    movw %ax, %sp

    /* reading disk */
    xorw %bx, %bx
    movw %bx, %es
    movw $0x7e00, %bx
    movw $0x0201, %ax
    movw $0x0002, %cx
    movb $0x00, %dh
    int $0x13

    /* Disable a20 through bios */
    movw $0x2400, %ax
    int $0x15

    /* clear through keyboard controller */

    call clear_8042 

    movb $0xd1, %al
    outb %al, $0x64
    call clear_8042

    movb $0b11011101, %al /* bit 0 = reset, must be 1, 
                 bit 1 = a20 gate */
    outb %al, $0x60
    call clear_8042

    movb $0xff, %al
    outb %al, $0x64
    call clear_8042

    /* 0xffff0 + 0x7e0e = 0x107dfe*/
    movw $0xffff, %bx
    movw %bx, %es
    movw %es:0x7e0e, %dx

    pushw %dx
    call printhex
    addw $0x2, %sp
loop:
    jmp %cs:loop

clear_8042:
    pushw %ax
    in $0x64, %al
    test $2, %al
    jnz clear_8042
    popw %ax
    ret


.= onboot+510
.word 0xaa55 /* little endian will reverse */
printhex:
    pusha
    movw %sp, %bp
    
    movw 18(%bp), %dx
    movw $0x0404, %cx /* ch = nibbles count, cl = iterator */
printhex_loop:
    movw $0x0e0f, %ax   
    rol $4, %dx     /* dl = nibble to show */
    andb %dl, %al   /* take a copy of dl in lowwer al nibble */
    addb $0x90, %al /* if al is decimal nibble = 0x90 - 0x99 
            else               = 0x9A - 0x9F */ 
    daa     /* if decimal = 0x90 - 0x99
            else 0x0 - 0x5 w/ CF    */
    adc $0x40, %al /* if decimal = 0xD0 - 0xD9
            else 0x41 - 0x46    */
    daa     /*if decimal = 0x30 = 0x39
            else 0x41 - 0x46    */
    int $0x10
    dec %cl
    jnz printhex_loop
    popa
    ret
```

The output from following instruction

`movw %es:0x7e0e, %dx`

must be 0xaa55 (if a20 gate is DISABLED), but for some reason it acts like a20 gate is enabled (output is 0x0000).

What am i doing wrong? I've been trying disabling it with bios interrupts, and kbc controller as you see.

Using manjaro and qemu, if makes difference.

Comment: Are you sure qemu supports it?

Comment: idk, ive compiled seabios with a20 disabled config, and output is still 0.
i remember when i runned qemu on my ubuntu 2 weeks or so ago, it runed as intended.

Comment: Works here using qemu 2.8.1(Debian 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4).

Comment: it outputs aa55?

Comment: Yes, it does. I had to rearrange the code a little since you put the `printHex` into the next sector and there is no code to load it so I moved that into the first 512 bytes.

Comment: thank you sir! now i will concentrate on fixing qemu